# Runing WebKitBrowserTest project of WebKit .net

Tags: c#, .net, webkit

I am trying to run WebKitBrowserTest project which comes with WebKit .net but I can't seem to get it to work. Navigate function is called and webView.mainFrame().loadRequest((WebURLRequest)request);
is executed and steps into decidePolicyForNavigationAction and by default it was not implemented. What do I do to get this browser running?

```
public void decidePolicyForNavigationAction(WebView WebView, CFDictionaryPropertyBag actionInformation, WebURLRequest request, webFrame frame, IWebPolicyDecisionListener listener)
{

}
```